# Download Images with zip File

Tags: php, ajax, image, pdf, zip

I am generating dynamic images from API.

And on **button click** i want to download a zip file with images .

I tried many solution, but still not able to download zip file with images

Comment: You say you have tried many solutions... _but what have you got to show for it?_

Comment: Also what exactly is it you want to do: simply download a certain zip? Or compress images to zip and then download?

Answer (score 0):

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = time().".zip"; // Zip name
$zip->open($zip_name,  ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $path = "uploadpdf/".$file;
      if(file_exists($path)){
          $zip->addFromString(basename($path),file_get_contents($path));  
      }else {
          echo"file does not exist";
      }
}
$zip->close()
```